# Slick slider - Add class to 'slick-active'

Tags: css, class, slider, carousel, slick.js

I am working with slick slider.

Does anyone know how to add a class to the 'slick-active' slider?

I am showing 3 slides and I would like to have a different class on each one: one class for the left slide, another for the center and another for the slide on the right.

For example, for the active left slide: 'slick-active-left'.

[image]

Comment: show your code to reproduce the problem, thanks

Comment: @DanielH added. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, just use **Adjacent sibling selectors (+)** `.slick-active` for 1st match, `.slick-active + .slick-active` for 2nd match, `.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active` for the 3rd one:

```
.slick-active {
  background: red;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active {
  background: blue;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

> ## Adjacent sibling selectors
>
> former_element + target_element { style properties }
>
> This is referred to as an adjacent selector or next-sibling selector. It will select only the specified element that immediately follows the former specified element.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```js
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.slick-active {
  background: red;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active {
  background: blue;
}

.slick-active + .slick-active + .slick-active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing work for me flawless.. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a class to each slider, you can target them already using CSS.Use the child selector to target the left slide, nth-child(1), the middle slide, nth-child(2) and the last slide, nth-child(3). Here is the CSS:

```
.slick-active: nth-child (1) {
/* Your CSS here */
}
```

Update as the CSS solution did not solve the issue because the slide class is being added through JS. You can use jQuery to target the slide. Just make sure it loads after the JS file.

```
<script>
jQuery('.slick-active:nth-child(1)').addClass('first-slide');
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried, but it's adding the 'slick-active' with JS, so the nth-child doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best native way to achieve your goal should be something like this:

```
$('#your-slider-element').slick({/configuration-object/}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
 $(this).find('.slick-slide[data-slick-index="'+nextSlide+'"]').addClass('customClass');
 $(this).find('.slick-slide[data-slick-index="'+currentSlide+'"]').removeClass('customClass');
});
```

Don`t forget to remove your custom class before moving to new slide!
Reference: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ - search for beforeChange